# Is Noetherian module over Noetherian ring a finitely generated module over that ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring and $M$ be a $A$-module.

Then if I am correct, $M$ is Noetherian  $A$-module if $M$ is finitely generated $A$-module.

Does the converse hold true ?

> i.e., Is a Noetherian module always finitely generated over Noetherian ring ?

---

It seems to me that Noetherian module is stronger than finitely generated module, because every submodule (and hence itself) of Noethrian module is finitely generated.

Is a Noetherian module over any ring a finitely generated module ?

Thanks

Comment: Why negative vote ? You can instead suggest to improve the question

Comment: Every ring is finitely generated over itself but it may not be necessarily Noetherian.For eg: take polynomial ring over infinite variables it is not noetherian but it is f.g. module over itself.